# Pandas finding closest matching n rows in a dataframe based off an input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies if this sort of thing has been asked. I haven't been able to completely find something that fits what I need.

Here's a sample dataset I'm working with:

| Age | Height | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 70 | 120 |
| 27 | 50 | 160 |
| 34 | 66 | 140 |
| 29 | 40 | 170 |
| 27 | 50 | 160 |
| 34 | 66 | 140 |
| 29 | 40 | 170 |
| 27 | 50 | 160 |
| 34 | 66 | 140 |

etc.

A "user" will be able to enter their Age, Height, and Weight as an input. I've written a simple class to save this input and convert it to a separate dataframe:

```
class new_data:
    def __init__(self, Age, Height, Bra, Weight, Bust, Waist, Hips):
        self.Age = Age
        self.Height = Height
        self.Weight = Weight
        
    def for_dict(self):
        return {
            'Age': self.Age,
            'Height': self.Height,
            'Weight': self.Weight,
        }

test = [new_data(Age = 20, Height = 30, Weight = 102] #sample data
df_input = pd.DataFrame.from_records([i.for_dict() for i in test])
```

I want to be able to take that df_input, and try to find the best matching rows from my initial dataset to then give as feedback to a "user". I've been chewing on whether to go individually to each column, find a few close matches, and then continue to try a match based off that sort. I want to be able to present a sort of percent match at the end of the process as well.

I'm still learning Python so definitely any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So what is the exact logic and expected output? Do you mean _closest_ as in distance? and want to return indices where the distance is minimum?

Comment: I think that's what I'm still trying to flesh out. I would say to start I want to find the indices where the distance is minimum. Any ideas for there? I assume I would have to norm of the difference in the vectors or something like that. Though there may be better ways/models I could approach this with as well. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

One way using `numpy.linalg.norm`:

```
dist = np.linalg.norm(df - df_input.to_numpy(), axis=1)
indices = np.argwhere(dist == min(dist))
```

Output:

```
array([[0]], dtype=int64)
```